# UNUserNotification is sending notification instantly in ios

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local

I want to send a notification, on every 60 seconds interval, after application entered to the background. But when you enter the background, notification is sending immediately, after that every 60 seconds is sending notification. I don't want to send notification immediately, how can i do that?

Here is my code,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
    return true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello,", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Some", arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = NSNumber(value: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)
    content.categoryIdentifier = "com.mahmut.localNotification"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 60.0, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "60Sec", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request)

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you could use dispatch_after to add your UNNotificationRequest after application entered background 60s.

Comment: dispatch didn't work truly. I put my code in

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60.0) {
            
        }
notification is sending after 4 seconds, sometimes 40 seconds.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to be working fine

Comment: here is my test video.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/61x9x60guwzv3p4/notificationTest.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

try using it this way...  instead of 4 you could use your own time... and later in your function you can use the timer concept to send a notification every 60 seconds.

```
    let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 4)
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.callYourFunction() 
    })
```

Comment: hi sai, i am using swift3, and i tried 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60.0) { self.myfunction} and it didnt work.

Comment: i have used this in swift 2.3.... my scenario is that I used this viewDidLoad function. I want to delay a particular func which fetches coordinatesof current location. Since the simulator has no location.. i used to simulate a location before the 4 seconds. later i have to update my coordinates every 10 seconds and used timer concept for it

Comment: I am not sure if it is exactly the code in swift 3 but did you try the exact code??